# Multiple AutoCompleteTextView in fragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a second AutoCompleteTextView (that gets objects from a Web API) in a fragment, but it never retrieves anything.

Currently testing on an Emulator, on API level 24. I have previously tried the code for this AutoCompleteTextView in another activity and it worked as intended there.

Fragment Code

```java
package com.advatek.timewin.fragments;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.advatek.timewin.MainActivity;
import com.advatek.timewin.R;
import com.advatek.timewin.helper.APICall;
import com.advatek.timewin.helper.APIHelper;
import com.advatek.timewin.helper.AutoSuggestAdapter;
import com.advatek.timewin.helper.JSONHelper;
import com.advatek.timewin.helper.JobSuggestAdapter;
import com.advatek.timewin.models.Employee;
import com.advatek.timewin.models.Function;
import com.advatek.timewin.models.PayPeriod;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Clock.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Clock#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Clock extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    private Context context;
    Handler handler;
    Handler jobHandler;
    AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView txtEmpSearch;
    AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView txtJobSearch;
    AutoSuggestAdapter autoAdapter;
    JobSuggestAdapter jobAdapter;
    private static final int TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE = 100;
    private static final long AUTO_COMPLETE_DELAY = 300;

    private static List<Function> functionList;
    PayPeriod period;


    private TextView txtPayWeek;
    Spinner spnJobs;

    Button btnSignIn;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Clock() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView getTextView(){
        return txtEmpSearch;
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Clock.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Clock newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Clock fragment = new Clock();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        context = getContext();
        period = new PayPeriod();
        functionList = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            WeekTask wTask = new WeekTask();
            wTask.execute().get();

//            JobTask task = new JobTask();
//            task.execute();

            txtJobSearch = (AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.txtEmpLookup);

            jobAdapter = new JobSuggestAdapter(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            txtJobSearch.setThreshold(2);

            txtJobSearch.setAdapter(jobAdapter);

            // Fires when an Employee is selected
            txtJobSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                    Function job = (Function) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setJob(job);

                }
            });

            txtJobSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    jobHandler.removeMessages(TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE);
                    jobHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE, AUTO_COMPLETE_DELAY);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(txtJobSearch.getText().toString().equals("")){

                    }
                }
            });

            jobHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    if (msg.what == TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(txtJobSearch.getText())) {
                            getJobs(txtJobSearch.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Error");
            dialog.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clock, container, false);
        txtEmpSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpLookup);
        txtJobSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.txtJobSearch);
        btnSignIn = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clock, container, false);
    }


    /**
     * Gets the Current Pay Period and Sets up the AutoCompleteTextView
     */
    private class WeekTask extends AsyncTask<PayPeriod, Void, PayPeriod>{

        @Override
        protected PayPeriod doInBackground(PayPeriod... payPeriods) {
            return new APIHelper().getCurrentPayWeek(JSONHelper.getDateAsInt());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PayPeriod payPeriod) {
            period = payPeriod;
            txtPayWeek = getView().findViewById(R.id.txtPayWeekNo);
            txtPayWeek.setText(getString(R.string.txtCurrentWeek, payPeriod.getPayWeekNo()));

            txtEmpSearch = (AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtEmpLookup);

            autoAdapter = new AutoSuggestAdapter(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            txtEmpSearch.setThreshold(2);

            txtEmpSearch.setAdapter(autoAdapter);

            // Fires when an Employee is selected
            txtEmpSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                    Employee emp = (Employee) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setEmployee(emp);
                }
            });

            txtEmpSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    handler.removeMessages(TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE, AUTO_COMPLETE_DELAY);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(txtEmpSearch.getText().toString().equals("")){

                    }
                }
            });

            handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    if (msg.what == TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(txtEmpSearch.getText())) {
                            makeApiCall(txtEmpSearch.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });


        }
    }

    private void getJobs(String term){
        APICall.getJobsByPartial(context, term, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                List<Function> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
                try{
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    jobs = new APIHelper().populateFunctionList(array);
                    jobAdapter.setData(jobs);
                    jobAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above does work, the issue was with how I was testing it. I had to use the first AutoCompleteTextView, pick a suggestion, then use the second one. If I tried to use the second one first, it does not work.